# 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type String. in line 42 and 57

Tags: actionscript-3, calculator

//This code is for a calculator that i am making as a school project but I keep getting this error code in two lines (42, 57)

//This is line 42 of my code (displayTxt.text = total;)

//This is line 57 of my code (memoryNumber=currentNumber;)

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var currentNumber:Number= 0; var memoryNumber:String=""; var operator:String = "";

input_0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_4.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_5.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_7.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_8.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
input_9.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, numberPushed);
action_point.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_equals.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_divide.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_multiply.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_subtract.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_add.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_clear.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
action_clearall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);

function sum(operator):void{
var total:Number
switch(operator){
    case "-":
    total = Number(memoryNumber) - Number(currentNumber);
    break;
    case "+":
    total = Number(memoryNumber) + Number(currentNumber);
    break;
    case "/":
    total = Number(memoryNumber) / Number(currentNumber);
    break;
    case "*":
    total = Number(memoryNumber) * Number(currentNumber);
    break;
}
displayTxt.text = total;
currentNumber = Number(displayTxt.text);
operator=""
memoryNumber=""
}
function buttonPushed(m:MouseEvent):void{
if(m.currentTarget.name=="action_point"){
    displayTxt.appendText(".")
    action_point.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPushed);
}else if(m.currentTarget.name=="action_equals"){
    if(operator!=""){
        sum(operator)
    }
}else{
    var whichOne:String = m.currentTarget.name;
    memoryNumber=currentNumber;
    displayTxt.text = "";
    switch(whichOne){
        case "action_divide":
        operator="/"
        break;
        case "action_multiply":
        operator="*"
        break;
        case "action_subtract":
        operator="-"
        break;
        case "action_add":
        operator="+"
        break;
        case "action_clear":
        currentNumber= 0;
        break;
        case "action_clearall":
        currentNumber= 0;
        memoryNumber="";
        break;
    }
}
}
function numberPushed(m:MouseEvent):void{
if(m.currentTarget.name.slice(-1)==0){
    if(currentNumber>0 ){
        displayTxt.appendText(m.currentTarget.name.slice(-1));
    }
}else{
    displayTxt.appendText(m.currentTarget.name.slice(-1));
}
currentNumber = Number(displayTxt.text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same issue in both lines:

Line 42: displayTxt.text = total.toString();

Line 57: memoryNumber = currentNumber.toString();

"total" and "currentNumber" are both Numbers, not strings, so you need to cast them first before assigning them to a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Type Casting to auto-convert from type `Number` into a `String` of text.

Look at your : `var memoryNumber:String=""; var currentNumber:Number= 0;`

Instead of `memoryNumber=currentNumber;` it should be `memoryNumber = String(currentNumber);`

Read more about Casting here : [Casting in AS3](https://bobthecoolguy.wordpress.com/2011/04/02/casting-in-actionscript-3/)

Comment: The actual question is why the memoryNumber a string ? Numbers should be kept as numbers and be casted to strings if needed. Usually the only case when you need the number as string is when you want to display the value in a textfield

Comment: @Philarmon I'm guessing they want it as String to show in textfield later as you say. Ofcos they could **and** should keep as Number and then cast to String for textfield but hey some people like to melt their CPU so... Also the other question is looking at their `function sum` they already do casting a lot but suddenly forgot how do it for fixing the error, I ask myself what happened there?